# How long is the wait after a file is renamed to when it is searchable in Finder or File Upload?

Tags: macos, finder, mojave

I am using macOS Majave, and sometimes I need to upload a file from Google Chrome.

So I searched for the file in the folder Downloads or Documents, and let's say the file is found:

```
abcdef 12345678.pdf
```

so I renamed it to:

```
record docs - abcdef 12345678.pdf
```

and now go to Google Chrome, close the upload file finder and re-open it (just to refresh it).

But I found that if I search for the file "record" (by filename) or "docs" (by filename), the file cannot be found.  I had to type in `12345678` and match by filename to find the file. (and it will show the file as "abcdef 12345678.pdf")

There seems to be a delay for when the file is renamed to when it can be found. What usually is this delay and can it be speeded up?